# How can I manage to solve an issue while using su -s?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, superuser

I am getting some permission issues using Docker and the following documentation suggests some command to run and one of them is su -s ${USER} but it does not work since the output is that there is no file or folder of that type, may you help me? I am on Ubuntu 16.04

This is the documentation I was following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fix here? Are you unable to run the docker runtime on the host (ie. "socket.... permission denied"), or are you having access problems inside the container?

Comment: I am unable to run the docker runtime on the host

Comment: That works thank you Frank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out some post-installation steps [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) on how to allow docker runtime to run without being root.

TLDR assuming you have root permissions

```sh
sudo groupadd docker            # add the docker group if not already extant
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER   # add the user to the group docker
exec $SHELL                     # reload your shell
```